# Rotate Logs Older Than 7 days and Delete Archive

Tags: logs, logrotate

I'm trying to configure `logrotate` to find all the log files older than 7 days from certain directories and archive them. The archived files must be deleted.

I have a structure as follows.

```
/var/log/myapp/subfolder1/*.log (hundreds of logs)
/var/log/myapp/subfolder2/*.log (hundreds of logs)
/var/log/myapp/subfolder3/*.log (hundreds of logs)
/var/log/myapp/subfolder4/*.log (hundreds of logs)
```

I know I should create a configuration file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`, but how can I specify the archiving of log file older than 7 days in each directory and remove the archived files?

Comment: are you asking logrotate to *rotate* these files, or just delete them? You may want to use a different tool if you just want to delete old files.

Answer (score 1):

```
#While waiting for a real answer, you may wish to play w/ the following
#following alternative outline of a solution not using "logrotate"
#Needs sanity checks, failure recovery, et cetera
find $myLOGHOME -type f -mtime -7 | tee $myARCHIVE_FILES

#After archiving & renaming old files, $mySTREAM_ARCHIVER moves
#the originals to a holding directory, where they will be maintained
#for some time before eventually being deleted when they are too old
#Holding directory files remain there 
$mySTREAM_ARCHIVER $myOPTIONS < $myARCHIVE_FILES

#Implementation, testing and cleanup are left as an exercise for the reader
```